# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I have tried accessing the docker container mysql command line from outside of the docker container and from within. I am receiving the error above each time. I have also reset the docker container and that also failed to work. I have used the following commands

docker exec CONTAINER /usr/bin/mysqldump -u root --password=root DATABASE > backup.sql
sudo docker exec -it CONTAINER mysqldump -h localhost -P 3306 = protocol = tcp -u root -p PASSWORD DATABASE > LOCATION

Comment: You're not using the right password. Consult your image's documentation for the default one, or reset it.